# i am subtracting two variables in python

Tags: python

i am subtracting two variables in python . one variable from input and another one predefined . i am getting error it shows "      y=name - name2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'   "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRaMM.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] since your first question is not well received here. Your question might be better received if you spellcheck it and use proper punctuation (use capitals at start of a sentence, etc.). Use code formatting for code and error messages to make it more readable. Do NOT post images. And most importantly: first [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22TypeError%3A+unsupported+operand+type%28s%29+for+-%3A+%27str%27+and+%27int%27%22) for an answer before posting a new question. This question has been asked and answered many many times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` function in python returns string by default, so if you want to use mathematical operations, you have to converts that string to `int` or `float`.

following code should work

```
import time

number1 = int(input("Enter Your Number: ")
number2 = 5000

y = number1 - number2

print("Your age is ", y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast(convert) the input value to int.

**This your code according to the image**

```py
import time

name = input("Enter your number:" )

names = 5000

y = name - name2

print("your age is ", y)
```

**Change it to this**

```py
name = int(input("Enter your number:" ))

names = 5000

y = name - name2

print("your age is ", y)
```